# При нажатии на кнопку пропадает фон

Tags: php, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<center><h1><font face=monospace color= Yellow size=9 >Арбитражное дело </font> </h1>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url(1.jpg); /* Путь к фоновому изображению */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* повторение картинки */
    background-size: cover ;}     /* При маштабе картинка не уменьшается*/
   div {
    margin-top: 3%; /* Отступ сверху */  }
   </style>
<br><br><font size="4" color="Snow" face="Arial">Выберите категорию дела:</font>

<select id = k>
<option value ="Взыскание необсновательного обогащения и долга по поставке"> Взыскание необсновательного обогащения и долга 

по поставке</option>
<option value ="О признании права собственности">О признании права собственности</option>
<option value ="Взыскание задолженности по договорам">Взыскание задолженности по договорам</option>
<option value ="Спор со страховой компанией"> Спор со страховой компанией</option></select><br><br>
<input type = button value = "Вывод списка дел" onclick = "obj ()">
<script>
 var delo = new Array;
 delo['nomer']= [1,2,3,4];
 delo['kategoriy']=["Взыскание необсновательного обогащения и долга по поставке", "О признании права собственности", 

"Взыскание задолженности по договорам", "Спор со страховой компанией"];
 delo['data']=["25.01.2014","10.07.2015","19.11.2015", "05.04.2016"];
 delo['summa']=["1600","2500", "7400", "11500"];

document.write("<div><table border=1 bgcolor=Yellow align = center><caption><h1><font face=MV BOLI>Список 

дел</font></h1><tr><td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Номер дела </td> <td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Категория дела </td> 

<td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Дата принятия заявления в производство </td> <td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Сумма исковых 

требований </td> </tr>");
for (i=0; i<delo['nomer'].length; i++)
{
document.write("<tr> <td align = center>"+delo['nomer'][i]+"</td> <td align = center>"+delo['kategoriy'][i]+"</td> <td align 

= center>" + delo['data'][i]+"</td> <td align = center>"+delo['summa'][i]+"</td> </tr>");
}

document.write ("</table> </div>");



function obj() 
{

var k = document.getElementById('k').value; 
  document.write("<div><table border=1 bgcolor=Yellow align = center><caption><h1><font face=MV BOLI>Список 

дел</font></h1><tr><td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Номер дела </td> <td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Категория дела </td> 

<td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Дата принятия заявления в производство </td> <td align=center bgcolor=Green1> Сумма исковых 

требований </td> </tr>");
  for (i=0; i<delo['nomer'].length; i++)
  {
  if (k==delo['kategoriy'][i])
  {
   document.write("<tr > <td align = center>"+delo['nomer'][i]+"</td> <td align = center>"+delo['kategoriy'][i]+"</td> <td 

align = center>" + delo['data'][i]+"</td> <td align = center>"+delo['summa'][i]+"</td> </tr>");
  }
  }
document.write ("</table>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```